# What is the bus- queue in MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

When a consumer connects to a receive endpoint, a uniquely named exchange and queue is created such as:
`bus-{MachineName}-{ApplicationName}-{Identifier}`

What is the purpose of this queue / exchange? Are there any docs detailing this?

Answer (score 1):

This a non-durable queue and exchange per endpoint, used to handle request-response. Responses are sent to that address, as well as faults.